# How do I use a model in keras with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, keras

i made a neural network with a (20,20) grid (shape = (20,20,1)) input and a vector of size 4 (shape = (4)). 
i want to use it on a sample of size 1.
So if X1 is a (20,20,1) tensor and X2 a vector of 4 numbers, i would like to use it by typing something like:
model.predict([[X1],[X2]])
to get an output.
if got the error :
"Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)"

i tried a lot of things and searched google without finding anything so i'm asking here.

here is the code:

```
grid_input = keras.Input(shape = (20,20,1))
info_input = keras.Input(shape = (4))
    
    
x = layers.Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation = 'relu')(grid_input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)

x =keras.Model(inputs = grid_input, outputs = x)

y = layers.Dense(20)(info_input)
y = layers.Dense(5)(y)
y = keras.Model(inputs = info_input, outputs = y)

combined = layers.concatenate([x.output,y.output])
z = layers.Dense(2)(combined)
z = layers.Dense(4,activation = "linear")(z)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)

X1 = []

for i in range(20):
    X1.append([])
    for j in range(20):
        X1[-1].append([0])


X2 = [12,2,3,7]
```

model summary :

```
Model: "functional_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 20, 20, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 18, 18, 1)    10          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 9, 9, 1)      0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 7, 7, 1)      10          max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 4)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 3, 3, 1)      0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 20)           100         input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 9)            0           max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 5)            105         dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 14)           0           flatten[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 2)            30          concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 4)            12          dense_2[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 267
Trainable params: 267
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I think you will have to convert your inputs using `np.asarray(input_list)`? You might be sending in a list instead of a np array

Comment: @ anurag reddy Thx for the reply. i tried "model.predict(np.asarray([[X1,X2]]))" and "model.predict(np.asarray([X1,X2]))". It doesn't work and i have the same error.

Comment: try `np.asarray(input_list, dtype=np.float32)`. that might be the problem, the dtype isprobably object

Comment: i changed X1 and X2 to np arrays of dtype float32 like you said and tried a bunch of things but i can't get it to work. In fact i don't even know what i should put in parameters of model.predict, should i put : [ [X1], [X2] ] , or [[X1,X2]], or [X1,X2] or something else?

Comment: Hey @Maxime Weill, can you check the model summary. It will show you the correct dimensionality required for your inputs.

Comment: @anuragReddy hey. i tried this, in the first row, "input layer", and in the column "output-shape" (pretty sure it correspond to input shape of my model), it's written [ ( None, 20, 20, 1) ]. A bit further, a second input layer of output shape = [(None, 4)].

Comment: @anuragReddy i've added the model summary in the post